# How to upload multiple images and object data in Angular js to Spring Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-boot

[image][image]
Request Multipart file from Angular js is not getting mapped to Spring Controller Request Parameter file.

My Angular Js Code to uplaod multiple images and object data looks like below
           Angular Js Controller:

```
                  AdminService.addImage($scope.gallery, 
                                  $scope.logo.image).then(function(success) {
                         AlertService.alert("Addded Successfully")
                         $scope.back();
                         $scope.isLoading = false;
                     }
```

> Service Js file

```
    adminServ.addImage= function(obj, file) {
         var deferred = $q.defer();
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append("advertisementRequestJson", JSON.stringify(obj));
                    formData.append("files", file);
                    $http.post(APP_CONFIG.API_URL + 'api/saveAdvertisementDetails', formData, {
                        transformRequest: angular.identity,
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': undefined
                        }
                    }).then(function(data) {
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    }, function(error) {
                        deferred.reject(error);
                    });
                    return deferred.promise;
                };
```

> HTML code is

```
         <input required name="name" ng-model="gallery.galleryName">
         <input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="logo.image" ngf-max-size="20MB" 
                                        name="file" accept="image/*" aria-label="logo" ngf-multiple="true">
```

> Spring Controller code :

```
        public @ResponseBody CommonResponseDTO saveGallery(
                    @RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file, 
                    @RequestParam(value = "requestJson", required = true) String requestJson){

                GalleryDTO galleryDTO = new GalleryDTO();
                galleryDTO.setMultipartFiles(file);
                galleryDTO.setRequestJson(requestJson);
                return galleryService.saveGallery(galleryDTO);
```

Comment: Do you get any response from the server? Any log?

Comment: Thier is not exception or log in server side , i have attached screen shot which shows files are in Javascript but not getting passed to Controller